# Eclipse Doesnt start

Tags: eclipse, software-installation

I installed eclipse and took help with some links and then I linked it with /usr/bin/eclipse but I am getting error that :-

```
bash: /usr/bin/eclipse: Permission denied
```

I tried this command `ls -l /usr/bin/eclipse` and got below given result.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Mar  8 20:36 /usr/bin/eclipse -> /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
```

So can someone suggest any solution, why eclipse is not running?

Comment: And if you run `/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse` directly instead of its symlink? Also, what is the output of `ls -l /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse` ?

Comment: Now there is one more error I had Installed the Android adt bundle so now eclipse has be initialized but on startup it is giving an error that could not find SDK folder '/home/gaurav/kubusoft/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/'. Is it because I had also copied the sdk along with the eclipse in the same adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030 folder in my /opt directory. And if so then how can I edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the file you're trying to execute is not executable. Try this:

```
chmod +x /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
```

If you installed Eclipse there as superuser, then run it with `sudo`:

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
```

After this you should be able launch Eclipse as either `/usr/bin/eclipse` or `/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/eclipse`.

Comment: Thanks janos that worked :) also thanks to Avinash . Can you Please tell me what was the error